# How can I rename a repository in Nexus Repository 3?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I am migrating from Nexus2 to Nexus3 and trying to do some cleanup along the way.

I would really like to rename some of the repositories that I am migrating as the repositoryID is less clear than the repository Name. And in Nexus 3 repositoryId and repositoryName are the same thing, but the migration takes the repositoryId and drops the repositoryName.

Is there any way to change the repositoryId?

Answer (score 2):

#### Changing **repository id** is not possible in NXRM3.

Unfortunately there is no distinct id and name fields in NXRM3.

As far as I am concerned they had to pick one to use and that was id because name did not have complete validation against being duplicated. So they would have to write some sort of repository name translating algorithm that still might not have been right.

#### The only solution is to recreate all repositories and name them accordingly.

Comment: how do you copy the repository contents after such recreation?